# General word for the "single or return"-ness of a travel ticket

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

As we all know, a plane ticket can be a "single" ticket or a "return" ticket. (Alternative terminology: a "one-way" vs a "round trip" ticket.) But is there a name for the set of ticket properties which includes "single" and "return" (and perhaps "multi", for a journey with multiple legs)?

For example, in this sentence:

> He asked me what **type** of ticket I wanted to buy: a single or a return.

Is there a word more specific than "type" which applies only to this particular property of a travel ticket?

Comment: I just looked at several airline booking websites. None of them have any label next to the choice of one-way or round-trip. I don't think there's a common hypernym for these concepts.

Comment: And looking at the underlying HTML, the names of the form fields seem to use phrases like "trip type".

Comment: BTW, I don't think "single" and "return" would be understood in American English. "return" sounds like a one-way ticket that you would buy to get home.

Comment: @Barmar yep, I realised that while talking to some American friends about my question. In the UK it's common to say "buying a return flight to X", which in isolation would be understood to mean that you bought tickets there and back, but in context could mean that you just bought a ticket for the return leg. "Round-trip" would probably only be used if you were actively trying to be unambiguous.

Comment: This one has been puzzling me as well. "Route", "Travel Type", "Trip Type" seem to be the most common descriptors.

Comment: Naming a type with only two choices seems more work than it’s worth so please, let’s not.

More interesting is that US Americans might see *a return from B to A* as meaning *a ticket from B to A, whence I came…*

*He asked me what type of ticket I wanted to buy: a single or a return?* is clearly a construct, not a quoted sentence. Even so, if you wanted to improve it why not try *He asked which I wanted: single or return?*

Comment: He asked me how many legs in my itinerary.

Comment: Two other types of itineraries (besides one-way and round-trip) are open jaw (the jaw can be open at either end, or both) and circle.  So there are more than two choices.

Comment: @Xanne - To my UK ear "round-trip" and "circle-trip" are synonymous...

Comment: @AndyT The circle trip may have many stops, however.  Because it returns to its origin, it will be priced differently from a series of one-ways, which it would otherwise be.

Comment: @Xanne - I knew exactly what you meant by a circle trip, the point I was trying to make is that I would also call it a "round trip". Circles are round, you know. ;) Apologies for the lack of clarity in my previous comment.

Comment: @AndyT: I wasn't clear earlier, for which I also apologize.  The problem is that whatever you think round trip means, it's just A-B-A to any travel agent, web site, anyone in the industry, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no specific word for this**.

You could invent one, but then you can't guarantee that the listener/reader will understand exactly what you mean.

E.g.:

> What **direction** is your ticket?

It comes close, but I wouldn't immediately understand what you mean. This seems more like I'm asking which one-way ticket you have bought (A to B, B to A), rather than asking you if you have a one-way or return ticket.

---

**A solution: don't name it**.

There no *need* for you to name this property, because you go on to list the options. Listing the possible options immediately clarifies what you're talking about.

So instead of "type", you could use the context-agnostic word "kind".

> [**Kind**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kind)
>   *noun*
>
> ***a kind of***
>        Something resembling.
>       *‘teaching based on a kind of inspired guesswork’*

For your example:

> He asked me what **kind** of ticket I wanted to buy: a single or a return.

Note that you can even omit listing the options, if this is part of a larger story, if the continuation inherently explains what is meant:

> He asked me what **kind** of ticket I wanted to buy.
>   Realizing that I was short on cash, I decided to buy a one-way ticket.

The context makes it clear what was being asked.

---

**Another solution: rephrase.**

Since "type" is awkward, and you can't think of a better word to use, why not avoid referring to it?

> He asked if I wanted to buy a return ticket.

A one-way ticket is the opposite of a return ticket, so it should be clear from context that you were asked whether you want a one-way or return ticket.

This also omits needing to refer to the "type" in any way, as the context ("return ticket") already makes it clear what is being talked about.

Answer (score 0):

> **Itinerary**
> [ahy-tin-uh-rer-ee, ih-tin-]
> /noun, plural itineraries.
>
> 1. a detailed plan for a journey, especially a list of places to visit; plan of travel.
> 2. a line of travel; route.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/itinerary)

I chose this word because your itinerary directly correlates with the distinction you are referring to. Even, if you have a single way ticket, you would still account for any layovers and the general route of travel.

Comment: This does not seem usable as a direct substitute for **type** in the example sentence. It would require a completely different sentence for it to work, and even them I'm not quite sure this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research, but examining the user-interfaces for the major travel websites.

None of them labeled the alternatives in a way visible to the user.

I checked the source code for the sites. Hipmunk.com internally refers to the attribute as... "type", as do Expedia and Orbitz. Skyscanner calls it "is-return".  ITA-Matrix puts the alternatives on different tabs.  Google Flights uses a meaningless code number.

In the industry, I cannot find a specific word .  Sorry.